# Service Getting Started Automatecally? In Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have 11 Services in my Android application. All the services have `PendingIntent`'s in broadcast receiver. I handle camera in one service and recorder in another service. But when I send an intent to start one or more of the services from `BroadcastReceiver`, recorder service is getting started automatically and it does not stop when I stop the started services.

Why does this happen? I have checked the code and recorder service is not started anywhere.

Comment: Without code, its impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, some code will be great. Your Recorder Service and AndroidManifest at least in case if you don't want to share all the code.